# Giving a user READ-ONLY permission on a workspace in APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a workspace created, in APEX and has a user associated with it (say, USER). I also have an ADMIN user. I want the USER to be able to just select the data from the schema tables and not update/delete tables or create a package etc. How can I achieve this?

I logged in as ADMIN and was tweaking some settings of the workspace. I saw an option called SQL Workshop. Enabling or disabling it doesn't serve my purpose. I want the user to be able to write queries (only select) but he must not be able to update the data or create packages or stuff like that.

Comment: This is not the sort of behaviour the APEX builder is built for. You're describing SQL Developer.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to accomplish this **within** the same workspace.  Anyone who can develop or administer a workspace can parse SQL as any database user (schema) mapped to that workspace.  You could achieve this using another workspace and normal database object privileges.

- Create a second workspace, which USER can login to.
- Selectively grant object privileges from objects owned by the database user of the
  first workspace to the database user of the second workspace.  E.g.,
  *GRANT READ ON dbuser1.table TO dbuser2;*

Comment: Are you suggesting to create one more schema in DB?

Comment: Yes, that's the only way you could control access via normal database privileges.

Comment: So, there cant be any way to have a single schema which has all the permissions but limited permissions for users (pointing to different workspaces) via apex UI, right? For instance, a schema having read-write permission and create package permission, but a user in a workspace pointing to this schema beaning able to only read-write but not package creation.. (_Adding this comment, since I felt my question can be a bit confusing_)

Comment: Correct.  Not possible.

Comment: Is there any reason that it is not implemented in APEX? Just curious...

Comment: Well.  It is solved in APEX, just across different workspaces.  We agree that it has to be 2 different schemas, right?  An application can only parse SQL as a single database user.  So what happens if you have an application which parses as DBUSER1?  Don't permit a restricted developer in the workspace to edit it?

Short answer - the feature is implemented, just across two different workspaces (with different DB users).  There hasn't been customer demand for any other requirements.  Plus, it's best to leave the privilege enforcement to the database.